# Pasting into an SSH session has repeating paste issues

Tags: ssh, putty, copy-paste, paste

This happens regardless of the SSH client (including PuTTY, KiTTY, and MobaXterm).

Pasting with Shift+Insert (since nothing else but a right-click will work) into an SSH terminal alongside other quick keypresses may duplicate the pasted characters and even eat following key presses.

Take this command for example:

```
$ cp file.txt <paste> <enter>
```

Let's say `directory/` is the copied text. When typing quickly enough, the result may look like this:

```
$ cp file.txt directory/directory/
```

With some testing, I found:

- Pressing something immediately before the paste will type that something and paste twice.
- Pressing something immediately after the paste will paste twice and ignore what was pressed, even if it was Enter.
- Pressing something immediately before and after will combine the results.

This means when I copy `b` and type `a<paste>c` in quick succession, the result is `abbb`.

I've dealt with this for years without any solution, but now it gets worse when my system resources are under a heavy load (like when using a virtual machine or docker containers on my main system). The result could be `abbbb` instead, even though I only pressed three buttons at half my usual typing speed.

Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: Does this happen with only a specific SSH server, or SSH servers on multiple machines?

Comment: If by SSH server, you mean the servers I am connected to, yes. Multiple servers, multiple machines, and multiple virtual machines alike.

I believe it to be an issue with the SSH programs (or the protocol itself?) and/or Windows, not the servers.